# I have tried to convert the image bitmap to file but I get "operation not permitted"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a page in my application where the user select an image from the gallery and save it as part of needed details. The image will be sent to a server through API request using Ktor. I have tried to convert the image bitmap to file but I get "operation not permitted" exception, and tired to look for a solution but nothing worked. One of the solutions recommended to add use permission for storage in the Manifest:

It didn't work as well.

---

The code is too long but here the block where I need to convert and save the file:

```
fun bitmapToFile(bitmap: Bitmap, fileNameToSave: String): File? { // File name like "image.png"
    //create a file to write bitmap data
    var file: File? = null
    return try {
        file = File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + fileNameToSave)
        file.createNewFile()

        //Convert bitmap to byte array
        val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos) // YOU can also save it in JPEG
        val bitmapData = bos.toByteArray()

        //write the bytes in file
        val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
        fos.write(bitmapData)
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()
        file
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText( context, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show()
        e.printStackTrace()
        file // it will return null
    }
}

fun handleChangeImage() {

    try{
        imageUri?.let {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, it)
            } else {
                val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.contentResolver, it)
                bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
            }
        }
        //fixme: file conversion throw operation denied error
        val fileName = imageUri?.lastPathSegment.toString().replace(":", ".")
        val fileInput = if (bitmap != null)
            bitmapToFile(bitmap!!, fileName)
        else null

        if(fileInput == null)
            throw Exception("Error")

        assetImageInput.value = fileInput
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        Toast.makeText( context, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText( context, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show()
    }

}
```

After converting the image it should be saved as "assetImageInput.value" and be sent through the API as a parameter.

Comment: `have a page in my application where the user select an image from the gallery ` You will then get an uri pointing to a file.

Comment: `and save it as part of needed detail` ????

Comment: `have tried to convert the image bitmap to file`?? I cannot follow you. You have no bitmap. You have an uri pointing to a file. Why do you wanna create another file? Use the uri directly to upload the picked file.